# Override Mass Virtual Hosting for One VirtualHost

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2

I'm not sure if that question was properly worded.

Basically, I have it set up via http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html so that I only have to create a folder (such as example.test) in my ~/Sites folder and I can go to http://example.test (granted my hosts file matches).

I am working on a couple projects that have a framework installed at one level above the public directory, so I was wondering if I could override the mass vhost for a single vhost.

I tried the following:

```
# I want this...
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/cameron/Sites/laravel.test/public
    ServerName laravel.test
</VirtualHost>

# ...to override this only for laravel.test
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/cameron/Sites/%0
```

The Laravel PHP framework installs the framework in level above the public like I was talking about, so when I go to http://laravel.test, I want it to go to `/Users/cameron/Sites/laravel.test/public` instead of `/Users/cameron/Sites/laravel.test/` if that makes sense...

But the above code doesn't work. It basically ignores anything before the last two lines.

So my question is... is there  a way to achieve what I want? Not necessarily the approach I'm trying, but I have a ton of local sites and 99% of them work great under the mass virtual host approach, I just occasionally want to override that behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`VirtualDocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#virtualdocumentroot) says to use `none` to turn it off, so I assume what you need to do is add that to your `<VirtualHost>` section:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/cameron/Sites/laravel.test/public
    VirtualDocumentRoot none
    ServerName laravel.test
</VirtualHost>
```

This isn't enough, though: when using `NameVirtualHost`, if an incoming request does not match the `ServerName`/`ServerAlias` of any `<VirtualHost>` block, then the first `<VirtualHost>` block is used, no matter what name it had.  In this case, it causes all of the other hostnames to this VirtualHost directive too.

A possible way to fix this would be to move the VirtualDocumentRoot directive into a `<VirtualHost>` block placed in the configuration before any other sites.  The `ServerName` of this block shouldn't matter, something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName bogusname
     UseCanonicalName Off
     VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/cameron/Sites/%0
</VirtualHost>
```

The bogus name should ensure that this VirtualHost will only be used in the "default" case of no other VirtualHosts matching the request.

Comment: This is making every site I have go to that DocumentRoot though, and not just laravel.test. Why is that? Shouldn't it only do the other stuff (i.e. turn off VirtualDocumentRoot) if ServerName is laravel.test? I am obviously missing something.

Comment: @CWSpear yeah, my answer is wrong.  I'll update it to explain why

Comment: This worked exactly like I wanted it to. Thank you very much!